# why is scala method serialisable while function not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark RDD defined like this:

```
val dataset = CreateRDD(data.filter(someFilter))
```

I observed the following:

```
//if filter is defined as function, such as following, 
//then spark will throw spark `task not serialisable exception`
val someFilter = (some) => true
//if filter is defined as method, such as following then everything will be fine
def someFilter(some) => true
```

why ?

yes, function/method are all defined as members in the test spec

Comment: Where are these definitions (val/def) declared? Are they declared as members of a Class? An Object? Or as local variables within some method's implementation? Behavior might differ between these options...

Comment: methods are not serializable.

Comment: Yes more context including exact error message is important.  It might be that in the first example the class is being captured in a closure for some reason.

Comment: @pedrofurla While methods may not be strictly serializable, spark will try to get around this by serializing the entire class to which they belong.

Comment: That's how general serialization work in the JVM, @DavisBroda. Btw, classes are not serialized too. Objects are serialized.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this:

```
val isNegative = (num: Int) => num < 0
```

is merely syntactic sugar for this:

```
val isNegative = new Function1[Int, Boolean] {
  def apply(num: Int): Boolean = num < 0
}
```

`Function1` is a Trait and the anonymous function created is not serializable. When you have something like this:

```
object Tests {
  def isNegative(num: Int): Boolean = num < 0
}
```

Now `isNegative` is a member of `Tests` which is serializable. When you call this:

```
val dataset = CreateRDD(data.filter(isNegative))
```

Spark needs to serialize `isNegative` before shipping it out to each node. Since objects are serializable if all it's members are serializable, when you use `def` it works fine, however when you use `val` Spark will instead try and serialize the value of `isNegative`, which is a non-serializable anonymous function and fail.